# Simple HTML code can't work inside ion-content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am facing a problem. I am trying to create something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xMpu4/224/):

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="a" class="panels">FIXED PANEL</div>
   <div id="b" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 1</div>
   <div id="c" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 2</div>
   <div id="d" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 3</div>
</div>

html,body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:black;
}

#wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.panels {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}

#a{
  background:#eee;
  position:fixed;
  color:red;
  top:0;
  z-index:-99;
}

#b{
  margin-top:100%;
  background:yellow;
}

#c{
  background:pink;
}

#d{
  background:green;
}
```

When I put this code inside ion-content, it simply doesn't work. I just see the first div, but I can't scroll to see the rest.

Comment: Why is your css in the html file? Put it in .scss first. Also, even if you want it in the html for some reason, you need to wrap it using <style></style> tags

Comment: Hi, it's not in the same file, obviously my html code is in a different file. I just put them together cause i don't know how to do it differently (first post, noob stack overflow :) )

Comment: FYI, I solved my issue by dividing the moving and fixed elements in different ion-content markups.